# how to enumerate listbox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi I'm new to Visual Studio and I am in need of a help in Visual Studio on a `Windows Form App`. also I don't really know if this is vb.net

I would like to make an application where if a user inputs something in the `TextBox`, it is presented in the `ListBox` whilst having some sort of an enumeration.

like for example.

If I type "Wow amazing" in the `TextBox` and confirm it. Then type another text like "I love you" in the `TextBox` and confirm it again

**It should show up in the `Listbox` as "1. Wow Amazing" and "2. I love you".**

Here's my code. I am not able to get it right and I don't really know how. I tried doing the `for` Loops and `Do While` but it would just duplicate the texts or am I doing something wrong?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim i As Integer = 0
ListBox1.Items.Add(i + 1 & ". " & TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why doesn't that work?  The i variable needs to be declared outside that scope.  Move it above the Button1_Click line.

Comment: It works although it is not what I have been seeking. when you start the debug, it would only input a single number. like:

Comment: 1.test 1.test2 it would show up like that

Comment: what I want is: 1. test 2. test2

Comment: if you get the point hehe

Comment: RioAblas you don't get LarsTech's point actually. but Michal has a solution for you. I would suggest you to read about scopes and have more practice

Comment: Yes, thank you. and Sorry for not understanding it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close!

On every button click you need to:

1. Take number of elements in list, to determine the number.
2. Insert text concatenated with number.

So, you should use this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Step 1
    Dim i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count + 1
    'Step 2
    ListBox1.Items.Add(i & ". " & TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate the help!